# $|x^{k}\varphi^{(q)}(x)| \leqslant C_{q}A^{k}$ if $|x|>A$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis

given

$$|x^{k}\varphi^{(q)}(x)| \leqslant C_{q}A^{k}k^{k\alpha}$$

I am told in a textbook that if the infinitely differentiable function $\varphi(x)$ vanishes for $|x|>A$ then

$$|x^{k}\varphi^{(q)}(x)| \leqslant C_{q}A^{k}$$

I dont really see how this is the case though. Could anyone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside the support of $\phi$ , $\phi^{(q)}=0$ also.  So for $|x|>A$, $x^k \phi^{(q)}(x) = 0$. For $|x|\le A$,
$$ |x^k \phi^{(q)}(x)| \le A^k \| \phi^{(q)}\|_{L^\infty(B(0,A))}. $$
taking $C_q = \| \phi^{(q)}\|_{L^\infty(B(0,A))} < \infty$  gives the result.

Comment: Oh I see. Actually it just lies in the fact that if $x < A$ then obviously $x^{k} < A^{k}$ and then we don't need the $k^{k\alpha}$ anymore